# error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `(&[_, ..], &[_, ..])` not covered

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Why Rust compiler complains about the code below with this error? It seems all possibilities are covered. Adding `_ => todo!()` solves the problem, but it is ugly. Is there another solution?

```
fn merge(left: &[u32], right: &[u32]) -> Vec<u32> {
        match (left, right) {
            ([], _) => right.to_vec(),
            (_, []) => left.to_vec(),
            (l, r) if l.first() < r.first() => {
                let mut t = vec![*l.first().unwrap()];
                t.append(&mut merge(&l[1..], &r[..]));
                t
            }
            (l, r) if r.first() <= l.first() => {
                let mut t = vec![*r.first().unwrap()];
                t.append(&mut merge(&l[..], &r[1..]));
                t
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `_ => unreachable!(),` since you as programmer can easily confirm this, this allows for additional optimizations as compared to using `todo`

Comment: @cafce25 False. Both optimize exactly the same. But `unreachable!()` represents the intent better.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, yes it answers, thanks. I added  `_ => unreachable!("Should never happen.")`